# VBScript is running batch file from the file path of VBScript, not path of batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am having a problem with a VBScript which was working just fine yesterday, but for some reason does not work today. I am attempting to run a batch file off the sever, from a VBScript in an adjacent server folder. The VBScript reads like this:

```
Dim Shell
Set Shell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Shell.run "cmd /K ..\Analyses\GeniE_SP.bat"
```

The VBScript is in a file in the folder ..\Local Design Calculations, whereas the batch file is in ..\Analyses. The script is calling up the batch file just fine, but when the batch file runs it is running with the file path of the VBScript. This is what is shown in the command window:

```
I:\Shared\Projects\105874\Local Design Calculations>REM @echo off
```

If I simply run the batch file from its actual location, there are no problems as the first line in the command window will read like this (as it should):

```
I:\Shared\Projects\105874\Analyses>REM @echo off
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Shell.run "cmd /K cd ..\Analyses & GeniE_SP.bat"
```

If the current active directory for the batch file is a requirement, first change it.

Answer (score 0):

You would specify the full path to what you want. There in no such thing as per drive default directories in WinNT. Graphical programs (ie normal) set their own default directory based on the folder the exe is in (and that's not a per drive default but a program default).

For console programs (ie non graphical) cmd.exe simulates per drive default directories.

SPECIFY FULL PATHS.